# Read all the Nodes in an XML file with Powershell and URLEncode the contents

Tags: xml, powershell

I am pulling an XML file from one source with my powershell script from a webpage into a local file.  The pulled file is saved to the hard drive and looks fine.  This XML file needs to be pushed to another site, but it fails their XML Schema Validation because some of the node data is not URL encoded.  The original XML file contained this data in a CDATA tag, but the other site is still failing the validation and a call to them indicates that all the data needs to be URL encoded.  Is there a way in powershell to read the contents of an XML file, URL Encode only the contents and write it back out?  I tried to use this code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
Get-ChildItem d:\temp\bvproductfeed.xml | % {
$encoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($(get-content $_.FullName))
$encoded | Out-File $_.FullName -Force
}
```

But this encodes the whole file.  I just need the text in the nodes encoded, not the whole file.

Here is a sample of the XML I need to read

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed xmlns="https://foo.bar/xs/15.3" name="Foo Products" incremental="false" extractDate="2017-10-20T13:21:41">
    <Brands>
        <Brand>
            <ExternalId>Test</ExternalId>
            <Name>Test Name</Name>
            <Names> 
                <Name locale="en_US">Test US</Name>
                <Name locale="sp_MX">Test Mexico</Name>
            </Names>
        </Brand>
    </Brands>
    <Categories>
        <Category>
            <ExternalId>Foo</ExternalId>
            <Name>Widget</Name>
            <CategoryPageUrl><![CDATA[http://foo.com/widget></CategoryPageUrl>
            <ImageUrl>http://foo.com/imageeditor/widget.jpg</ImageUrl>
            <ParentExternalId>Bar</ParentExternalId>
        </Category>
    </Categories>
    <Products>
        <Product>
                <ExternalId>90084</ExternalId>
                <Name>Foo-bar item 1</Name>
                <Description><![CDATA[<p>Description data with HTML tags ]]></Description>
                <BrandExternalId>test</BrandExternalId>
                <CategoryExternalId>Foo</CategoryExternalId>
                <ProductPageUrl><![CDATA[http://foo.com/90084]]></ProductPageUrl>
                <ImageUrl>http://foo.com/imageeditor/90084.jpg</ImageUrl>
                <ModelNumbers>
                    <ModelNumber>90084</ModelNumber>
                </ModelNumbers>
                <ManufacturerPartNumbers>
                    <ManufacturerPartNumber>90084</ManufacturerPartNumber>
                </ManufacturerPartNumbers>
                <UPCs>
                    <UPC>081483007601</UPC>
                </UPCs>
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                        <Value>Foo-bar</Value>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                        <Value>Foo</Value>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                        <Value>Bar</Value>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
            </Product>
    </Products>
</Feed>
```

There are many Brands, Categories and Products to traverse through, but each has this structure.  There are CDATA tags that need to be encoded, but for this other company their requirement is all values be URLEncoded.

Thanks.

Comment: All Element text or Attribute text or Both? Or is it just the CDATA text?

Comment: Add the XML contents or a sample to the question.

Comment: All element text, not the attribute text and CDATA

Comment: You need to show the *exact* result you expect from this. "Everything must be encoded" is too vague.

Comment: All of the values in the nodes need to be run through the HttpUtility.UrlEncode method so the values come back encoded.  So in the <Description> tag I read in the value, encode it and write it back into the <Description> tag.  The most critical values to replace are the CDATA tags.  Although by definition of CDATA should negate the need to URLEncode, it breaks their validation unless the CDATA is encode too.  So, Description and ProductPageUrl are the most critical to encode in the file.